# Custom tab names in xcode 10

Tags: user-interface, xcode10

Right now, my tab names default to the name of the currently-opened file. I can use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to individually rename tabs, but I'd like to name them automatically by their path relative to the project root, or maybe some other pattern. Is this possible in xcode 10?